# Understanding Bootstrap navigation classes and attributes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using Bootstrap. I found following HTML code to make the navbar. I want to understand everything I use though.

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
```

In this part, I dont understand the `data-target` and `data-toggle` atributte. I know that It has something to do with responsibility of the navigation, but I need to know how ecactly does It work.

Next, there is this part:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
```

Here I just need to know what all the used classes do.

Is there anyone capable of explaining those few things to me? I would really appreciate It.

Comment: have you tried examining the bootstrap documentation?

Comment: yes actually, didn't find the exact meaning of some of those things anyway.. @PlantTheIdea

Comment: even this part => http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse? cuz that really says it all ...

Comment: well, I don't get what `data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse"` does anyway... @PlantTheIdea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button` with `data-target` basically says this: this button controls the element with the same class/id that is the `data-target` attr. value of the button. In Bootstrap's JavaScript code it got some lines for this logic.

So `button` with `data-target="#my-navbar` will control the dropdown menu with `id="my-navbar"`, by default.

**Default behaviour** is that it shows contents of the navbar on click below 768px.

The `navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse` classes are applied to navbar and says that collapse to responsive mode below given `media query` (default is below `768px`). Class `collapse` is applied when the viewport is below 768px and it applies responsive classes (hides the navbar links below the hamburger `button`).

[Here's link from the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: And what does the `navbar-toggle` class do, please? @knitevision

Comment: @TomášNosek ? ``navbar-toggle`` is just a CSS class that gets applied to the button that toggles the showing/hiding of the ``navbar``

Comment: so it just says, that if you click on the button, the navbar shows? @knitevision